# Como deixar a posição de uma div fixa de acordo com a alteração de RaddioButton

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Tenho a seguinte tela que assim que muda a opção do `RaddioButton` a `div` desce ou sobe.
Gostaria de saber como deixar fixo em uma posição.

Selecionado a opção Ciclo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecionando a opção Ano:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aspx:

```
<div id="indicadores" style="display: none; margin-left: 447px; margin-top: -50px; height: 39px;" class="divFiltros">
    <asp:Label ID="Label40" runat="server" Width="85px" Style="margin-top: 15px;">TIPO RELATÓRIO</asp:Label>
    <div style="border: solid 2px; height: 28px; width: 314px; margin-left: 115px; margin-top: -27px;">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbIndicadores" name="rdbIndicadores" CssClass="radioItens" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Style="width: 319px;">
            <asp:ListItem Text="CICLO" Value="ciclo" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="ANO" Value="ano"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
.radioItens label {
    margin-left: -105px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 145px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: @DamonDudek Não, ela muda de posição conforme é selecionado, como nas imagens.

Comment: O seu CSS está tudo errado, o problema é um pouco maior! e você passou poucas informações para correção...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o que mais seria necessário para avaliar mas detalhadamente?

Comment: O conjunto inteiro de informações, css, javascript e html da página

Comment: Você quer deixar eles centralizados? Se for isso: display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;

Comment: Não, quero deixar a div que contém os 2 RaddioButtons fixa em uma posição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente alterar o position e remova o label, pois não identifiquei nenhum elemento label dentro do seu radioItens

```
.radioItens{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -105px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 145px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```